# Why does std::reduce need commutativity?

Tags: c++, c++17

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce

It says that the behavior of an operation is not defined if the operation is not commutative, but why? We just divide the array into blocks and then merge the result. Is it only necessary to have associativity?

Comment: Your link explicitly states that the operands can be rearranged.

Comment: @n314159 Yes, but *why*? I believe the question asks in what situation the implementation would have reason to use that allowance. E.g. is there a container where it might be faster to call `op(right, left)` over `op(left, right)` where `left` and `right` are the results of reducing the corresponding halves of the container? Why can't all containers just preserve the order? It certainly seems possible, so why does the standard make the allowance that it doesn't have to be so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::reduce` requires both associativity and commutativity. Associativity is clearly needed for a parallel algorithm, since you want to perform the calculation on separate chunks and then combine them.

As for commutativity: According to [a reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6v1gxo/c17_in_details_parallel_algorithms/dlyyyzn/) by MSVC STL developer Billy O'Neal, this is required in order to allow vectorization to SIMD instructions:

> Commutativity is also necessary to enable vectorization, since the code you want for reduce to come out as something like:
>
> ```
> vecRegister = load_contiguous(first);
> while (a vector register sized chunk is left) {
>     first += packSize;
>     vecRegister = add_packed(load_contiguous(first), vecRegister);
> }
> // combine vecRegister's packed components
> ```
>
> etc., which given ints and SSE registers and a * b * c * d * e * f * g * h gives something like (a * e) * (b * f) * (c * g) * (d * h).
>
> Most other languages aren't doing explicit things to make vectorizing their reduction possible. And nothing says we can't add a noncommutative_reduce or something like that in the future if someone comes up with a compelling use case.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior is actually **non-deterministic** if the operation between the operands is not commutative. "non-deterministic" is not the same as "undefined". Floating point math is not commutative, for example. This is one reason why a call to `std::reduce` may not be deterministic, because the binary function is applied in an unspecified order.

Refer to [this note](http://eel.is/c++draft/reduce#9) in the standard:

> Note: The difference between `reduce` and `accumulate` is that reduce applies `binary_op` in an
>   unspecified order, which yields a nondeterministic result for non-associative or non-commutative
>   binary_op such as floating-point addition. —end note ]

Comment: Same thing I said to n314159, on the question. This answer doesn't explain why the standard makes this allowance. The only answer that currently does is interjay's (EDIT: and n314159's).

Comment: @HTNW: From an implementers' standpoint, parallel sum results could be applied in any order, that's the nature of parallel work. forcing it to happen in a predictable fashion makes it slower.

Answer (score 1):

The standard defines the generalized sum as follows: [numeric.defns](http://eel.is/c++draft/numerics.defns)

> Define GENERALIZED_­NONCOMMUTATIVE_­SUM(op, a1, ..., aN) as follows:
>
> - a1 when N is 1, otherwise
> - op(GENERALIZED_­NONCOMMUTATIVE_­SUM(op, a1, ..., aK),
>     op(GENERALIZED_­NONCOMMUTATIVE_­SUM(op, aM, ..., aN)) for any K where 1
>
> Define GENERALIZED_­SUM(op, a1, ..., aN) as GENERALIZED_­NONCOMMUTATIVE_­SUM(op, b1, ..., bN), where b1, ..., bN may be any permutation of a1, ..., aN.

So, the order of summation as well as the order of operands is unspecified. So if the binary operation is not commutative or not associative, the result is unspecified.

That is also explicitly stated [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/reduce#9).

Regarding why: It gives the library vendors more freedom, so they may or may not implement it better. As an example where the implementation can benefit from commutativity. Consider the sum `a+b+c+d+e`, we first calculate `a+b` and `c+d` in parallel. Now `a+b` returns before `c+d` does (as it can happen, because it is done in parallel). Instead of waiting for the return value of `c+d` we now can directly compute `(a+b)+e` and then add this result to the result of `c+d`. So in the end, we computed `((a+b)+e)+(c+d)`, which is a rearrangement of `a+b+c+d+e`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does `std::reduce` need commutativity?

**For speed.**

If the operator is commutative, then you can rearrange the order of operations without affecting the results.

And if you can rearrange the order of operations, you can have different threads, or processes, or hardware accelerators or what-not working independently on some of the operations to be performed, and not care about the order in which they complete their partial sums, nor their internal ordering of operations, and then finally add up the partial sums whichever way is convenient.